# pySpark forEach function on a key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I can't seem to find much documentation on forEach. I have a dataset that is in key/value pairing. I am looking to do something like (pseudo code):

forEach key, sum the value
forEach key, max of the values
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This can be done e.g. with reduceByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs)

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("foo", 2), ("bar", 3)])

rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y).collect() # Sum for each key
# Gives [('foo', 3), ('bar', 3)]  

x.reduceByKey(max).collect() # Max for each key
# Gives [('foo', 2), ('bar', 3)]
```

Comment: Would it make sense to use 
reduceByKeyLocally for any of these functions?

Comment: So I did reduceByKeyLocally for max and min and it sped up just a fraction and also removed the need for the .collect()

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/programming-guide.html)

> foreach(func) Run a function func on each element of the dataset. This
>   is usually done for **side effects** such as updating an accumulator
>   variable (see below) or interacting with external storage systems.

Please note the highlighted "side effect". foreach is an action on RDD that perform function on each element in the RDD, but does not return anything to the driver. You can pass function to it such as println or increase accumulator variables or save to external storage.

In your use case, you should use **reduceByKey**.